# logo in div & height of div disappear after 10sec?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to hide a div and logo within it?

I have a logo which is a jpeg at the top of the screen, but after 10 seconds or so I want it to disappear, and the text below it move up to replace it.

I have found how to hide the logo, but I can't get the box to go to 0px and disappear so that the bottom panel or move up to replace the logo area.

anyway of doing this please?

[image: Here's what I want]

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout and http://api.jquery.com/slideup/ (or `.fadeOut()` or simple (non-animated) `.hide()`)

Comment: you can simply do it with css : see my answer

Comment: @לבני מלכה But removing only opacity, its height remains. Maybe this is a problem for OP. However, well, without his code we can't say it...

Comment: see my edit.. to remove space

Comment: @לבני מלכה Well done! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's hide method with a setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#topDiv").hide();
}, 10000);
```

Alternatively, you could delete the element entirely from the page:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#topDiv").remove();
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only css with [`animation`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

NOTE! if you remove  `99%{ opacity:1;}` the div will gradually disapear

```css
.logo{
background:blue;
height:0px;
width:50px;
opacity:0;
animation: hide 10s;
}
@keyframes hide {
    0% { opacity:1;height:50px; }
    99%{ opacity:1;height:50px;}
    100%{ opacity:0;height:0px;}
}
.content{
background:red;
height:50px;
width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
</div>
<div class="content">
</div>
```